# Layer not visible after deleting from attribute table QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-table, delete

I'm a newbie for QGIS and trying to learn.
I was editing the attribute table in which process I deleted some rows. Then the layer became invisible in the project. After trying a lot I decided to redo the project. To do so, I started a new project and reloaded the shapefiles from the zip file. But out of three layers the problematic shapefile still is not visible. 
What should I try next?

Comment: Is the file not visible **in the map** or not visible at all ? (layer manager ?)

Comment: It's not visible on the map. The layer is there. when I use select by location, the selected area gets highlighted. If I deselected all the other layers and leave that layer nothing is visible.

Comment: Ensure there's no **scale dependent visibility** _(Layer/Properties/General tab)_

Comment: Thanks but it's unchecked.

Comment: Before your editing your were seeing the layer without any problem ?

Comment: Yes, no problem at all. After I deleted some rows  it became invisible. Moreover,  I don't know why the layer doesn't show up for the particular layer when I create a new project.  Does Qgis store the error somewhere.

Comment: Your problem seems to be linked with **a** given layer of your dataset ... haven't you created some invalid geometries in your process ?

Comment: I have started it again afresh. How do I check  for invalid geometries? I didn't get error when I checked validity.

Answer (score 3):

The root cause of the problem is corrupt .shx file. Maybe after improper deletion of data from attribute table.

Comment: maybe a solution ... not an explanation ... weird ...

Comment: Please disregard the previous answer.  The root cause of the problem is corrupt .shx file. May be after improper deletion of data from attribute table.